# iOS - How to declare Swift enum property with unknown type?

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I am trying to create a Swift enumeration which would declare a property of `Type` so that I can call `Enum.type` from within a `JSONDecoder().decode` call. I would like the know the following:

1. Is this even possible in Swift?
2. What would the syntax look like?

I have given it the following attempt:

```
enum Item {
        case property1, property2, property3

        var type: Any<T> {
            switch self {
            case .property1: return ACustomObjectType
            case .property2: return AnotherCustomObjectType
            case .property3: return AThirdCustomObjectType
            }
        }
    }
```

Now obviously this doesn't compile, but the piece I want to call it from would look like:

```
JSONDecoder().decode(Item.type, from: data)
```

It is also entirely possible that I am just trying to be overly clever here, and there is a much simpler solution.

Comment: Show an example of the JSON you wish to parse.

Comment: @rmaddy I am not sure that's relevant here. In any case, the enum is meant to contain the type representations for several different custom model classes, each with different json responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution

```
class CustomObject:Decodable {
    var id:String
    var name: String
    var age: String
}

class ACustomObject: CustomObject {

}

class AnotherCustomObject: CustomObject {

}

class AThirdCustomObject:CustomObject {

}


enum Property  {
    case property1
    case property2
    case property3

    var type:CustomObject.Type {
        get  {
            switch self {
            case .property1: return ACustomObject.self
            case .property2:  return AnotherCustomObject.self
            case .property3: return AThirdCustomObject.self
            }
        }
    }


}
let dic = ["id": "122342", "name": "stackoverflow", "age": "22"]

let json = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dic, options: .prettyPrinted)

do {
    let result =  try JSONDecoder().decode(Property.property1.type, from: json)
    print(result.name)

}catch {
    print(error)
}
```